# Invalid argument from sendto in ansi C when trying to implement UDP

Tags: c, udp, debian-based

I know there are a few similar question on SO, but I feel like everyone has a different issue that is causing this. So I'm posting my particular case.

I'm working on the raspberry pi, using raspbian, a debian derivative. I'm coding in ansi C. This is a server that sends some data to a udp client on another end through port 500.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int sockfd;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;
   char buffer[256];

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(500);
   bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   sprintf(buffer,"hi this is a test \n");
   if(sendto(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr))==-1)
   { error("fail:")
    };

   return 0;
}
```

But this just gives me the error "invalid arguments", I can't figure out what could possibly be wrong. If the type of argument I supply to sendto is incorrect, this would fail on compile. But the type is correct and this compiles, only at runtime does it fail.

Comment: It's not related to the type of the arguments. `sockfd` for example can be any integer even if that integer doesn't refer to a socket. Thus, your code will compile but you'll get an error at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You have no initialization for the `cliaddr` structure. Thus, its contents are random. Your code compiles fine because you have a `struct sockaddr_in` where it should be but the compiler cannot check if you have properly initialized it.

On the other hand, at runtime when `sendto` is invoked the `glibc` or the kernel finds out that that random data in the `cliaddr` structure doesn't look like a valid address and throws up an `invalid argument` error.

**Solution**: initialize the `cliaddr` variable before using it.

Edit: You also need to properly initialize the socket, the third argument there shouldn't be `0`.

Second edit, **read me**: For resources I recommend [the extraordinary guide of Beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html). For your exact problem [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#sendtorecv) subchapter can help.

Comment: how do I initialize the cliaddr struct? I've been trying to find a good sample code and it seems the current one has completely led me astray.

Comment: See the links in the second edit. It is a good tutorial and you even have examples there.